# Is there possibility to ask OS to start application as administrator through a custom protocol?

Tags: windows, custom-protocol

I have an application FOO that does not usually need admin permissions. And also I have a link within website that allows me to start this FOO application.

By default that FOO is started with permissions of a user.
The only way to start FOO is by clicking a website link (parameters, that are passed to a client application are crucial).

In some cases, user needs to start that application from webbrowser with admin permissions. I want to have two links on a website, one of them - to allow users to start with usual permissions, another one- with elevated permissions.

Is there any parameter or modifier within custom protocol link that would allow me to tell OS on a target machine that I need to start my application as administrator?

**EXAMPLE**

```
<a href="Mycustomprotocol:baseurl=paramurl&username=paramname"> Click me for launch</a>
```

Comment: if FOO.exe is located on a network share, you can `right click it`, `properties`, `compatibility` >  check `run this program as an administrator`. you can also invoke the 'runas' command in a 3rd party exe\script. google "windows runas command"

Comment: @Stavm That's decided by a person who clicks the link in Webbrowser. The idea is good, but the end user is not supposed to operate with his Foo.exe locally. I would rather have two links on a website, one of them starting app in user mode, another, as administrator. But I'm not aware if that's possible to specify this second link.

Comment: can you please post some code that shows how you invoke foo.exe

Comment: <a href="Mycustomprotocol:baseurl=paramurl&username=paramname"> Click me for launch</a>

Comment: this means your users invoke the exe locally. you can use the `runas` command. point your users to a batch file instead of an exe, and have that batch file invoke `runas` foo.exe with the parameters passed to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364781/runas-does-not-allow-complex-arguments

Comment: @Stavm perfect. I thought of this mechanism, but was not sure how to implement it. Can you answer my question so that I could mark it as resolved?

Comment: @Stavm, the `runas` command-line tool is for running processes as a different user, not for running processes with elevated privilege.  (If you specify the local administrator account it will run the process elevated, but that account is disabled by default.)

Comment: Sasha, presumably your custom protocol is passing the parameters to the locally installed executable.  Couldn't you add an extra parameter asking the executable to self-elevate?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Great catch! I didn't think about it at all!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2081945/886887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [runas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680046(v=vs.85).aspx) command.

point your users to a batch file instead of an exe, and have that batch file invoke runas foo.exe with the parameters passed to it.

Example:
[runas does not allow complex arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364781/runas-does-not-allow-complex-arguments)

Comment: By default, the Administrator account is disabled, and `runas` won't work for any other account because of UAC.